# How avoid duplicate records when use annotate() in queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-orm

I get this queryset for some method an receive one record

```
candidates_qs = self.filter_job_type_language_zones(job_type_id, filter_languages, filter_zones)
```

Then i need to cast a charfield to integerfield to compare against some value

```
candidates_qs = self.filter_job_type_language_zones(job_type_id, filter_languages, filter_zones)
        candidates_qs = candidates_qs.annotate(
            # cast answer_text as integer to compare with question value
            as_integer=Cast('candidatejobtype__questions_answers__answer_text', IntegerField()))
```

After that my queryset have duplicated records. I try distinct() but didn't work. How avoid duplicate records?

Answer (score 0):

What about relation between models? In your annotation, there is a lookup so my assumption is that it could make duplicates.

There is only one object in queryset, but is in relation with many **questions_answers** and each has its own **answer_text**.

I think, some models definitions here would be helpful.